# SerializeObject/DeSerializeObject escapes references

Tags: c#, serialization

When I DeSerialize an object from file, the fields whit equal references, don't have same references any more.

This is an example:

in this example, I created an object `a1` from type `A`. then I saved it in a file and load it into new object named `a2`. In `a1` there is `b1` and `b2` which are same (equal references), so when I set `a1.b1.x = 5;`, the value of `a1.b2.x` will change to `5` also, but after save/load, when I set `a2.b1.x = 5;`, the value of `a2.b2.x` will not change!!!

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public class SerializeObjectTest
    {
        public static void Test()
        {
            var a1 = new A();
            a1.init();
            SerializeObject<A>(a1, "d:\\1.xml");
            var a2 = DeSerializeObject<A>("d:\\1.xml");
            a1.b1.x = 5; // this will change also the value of a1.b2.x
            a2.b1.x = 5; // this will not!!!!! change also the value of a2.b2.x
            MessageBox.Show(
                "a1.b1.x==a1.b2.x : " + a1.b1.x + "?=" + a1.b2.x + "\r\n" +
                "a2.b1.1==a2.b2.x : " + a2.b1.x + "?=" + a2.b2.x + "  !!\r\n", "Save.SaveAble"
                );
        }

        public class A
        {
            public void init()
            {
                b1 = new B() { x = 100 };
                b2 = b1;
            }
            public B b1;
            public B b2;
        }
        public class B
        {
            public double x;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes an object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="serializableObject"></param>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>
        public static void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
        {
            if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                    xmlDocument.Save(fileName);
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception here
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes an xml file into an object list
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T DeSerializeObject<T>(string fileName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) { return default(T); }

            T objectOut = default(T);
            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.Load(fileName);
                string xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

                using (StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlString))
                {
                    Type outType = typeof(T);

                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(outType);
                    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(read))
                    {
                        objectOut = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        reader.Close();
                    }

                    read.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception here
            }

            return objectOut;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is how `XmlSerializer` works.

Comment: Is there any settings to avoid this?

Comment: No. You'd have to implement your own custom XML serialization by implementing the `IXmlSerializable` interface.

Comment: what about internal fields? Can they be saved?  @OndrejTucny

Comment: `a1.init();` sets b2 to be the same reference as b1. This never happens in the deserialized class, hence the value doesn't change.

Comment: @stuartd : So a1 and a2 won't behave same, What will happen if I use this for save/load my project in my application??

Comment: If you were to add the line `a2.b2 = a1.b1;` in your example after the deserialization, the value would change. It's hard to say any more, though, as I don't know a) how your example relates to your actual code or b) why you have two fields pointing to the same reference.

Comment: @stuartd : this is just an example, but  in may actual project, some time it happens that in an array there is some repeated values (references are equal) and the should remain like it after save/load. Is there any suggestion? Is there a typical way to save/load the project's data in a c# application?

Comment: If you switch to a DataContractSerializer it does have attributes you can set to have references behave like you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed an project my self that can save/load/clone objects in c# and it keeps references to object, it is available [here](https://github.com/mrbm2007/ObjectSaver).

It also can save internal and private fields. There are some attributes to how save fields or types (like donsave, saveas, saveif, ...).